# Get attribute from XML RSS

Tags: xml, vba

I have an XML feed I'm trying to get some data from in Excel. Here's the [XML](http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=75240):

```
<rss xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Yahoo! Weather - Los Angeles, CA</title>
<link>
http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Los_Angeles__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0638_f.html
</link>
<description>Yahoo! Weather for Los Angeles, CA</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 26 Aug 2015 9:47 am PDT</lastBuildDate>
<ttl>60</ttl>
<yweather:location city="Los Angeles" region="CA" country="US"/>
<yweather:units temperature="F" distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph"/>
<yweather:wind chill="84" direction="0" speed="0"/>
<yweather:atmosphere humidity="55" visibility="7" pressure="29.97" rising="0"/>
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="6:20 am" sunset="7:25 pm"/>
<image>
<title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
<width>142</width>
<height>18</height>
<link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
<url>
http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif
</url>
</image>
<item>
<title>Conditions for Los Angeles, CA at 9:47 am PDT</title>
<geo:lat>34.05</geo:lat>
<geo:long>-118.23</geo:long>
<link>
http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Los_Angeles__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0638_f.html
</link>
<pubDate>Wed, 26 Aug 2015 9:47 am PDT</pubDate>
<yweather:condition text="Fair" code="34" temp="84" date="Wed, 26 Aug 2015 9:47 am PDT"/>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/34.gif"/><br /> <b>Current Conditions:</b><br /> Fair, 84 F<BR /> <BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR /> Wed - Mostly Sunny. High: 89 Low: 71<br /> Thu - Sunny. High: 89 Low: 72<br /> Fri - Sunny. High: 92 Low: 71<br /> Sat - Mostly Sunny. High: 88 Low: 69<br /> Sun - Mostly Sunny. High: 82 Low: 66<br /> <br /> <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Los_Angeles__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0638_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/> (provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]>
</description>
<yweather:forecast day="Wed" date="26 Aug 2015" low="71" high="89" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="27 Aug 2015" low="72" high="89" text="Sunny" code="32"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="28 Aug 2015" low="71" high="92" text="Sunny" code="32"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Sat" date="29 Aug 2015" low="69" high="88" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Sun" date="30 Aug 2015" low="66" high="82" text="Mostly Sunny" code="34"/>
<guid isPermaLink="false">USCA0638_2015_08_30_7_00_PDT</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
<!--
 fan1591.sports.bf1.yahoo.com Wed Aug 26 10:09:26 PDT 2015 
-->
```

How do I get the elements for the `yweather:condition`, as I'm trying to get the value for `"temp"`.  Or, for that matter, how do I get any of the info between `< ... >`, like `yweather:forecast`'s "high", "low", etc?

I know how to get child elements of more "pure" XML documents - for example, [this XML](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Avenue,%20Washington%20D.C.,%20USA&sensor=false) I am able to parse out info with the following:

```
Set resultnodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result")
For Each n In resultnodes
            Set latitudenodes = n.SelectSingleNode("geometry/location/lat")
            Set LongitudeNodes = n.SelectSingleNode("geometry/location/lng")
            Set addressNodes = n.SelectSingleNode("formatted_address")
            Set countyNodes = n.SelectSingleNode("address_component[type='administrative_area_level_2']/long_name")

If Not latitudenodes Is Nothing Then latitude = latitudenodes.Text
            If Not LongitudeNodes Is Nothing Then longitude = LongitudeNodes.Text
            If Not addressNodes Is Nothing Then altAddress = addressNodes.Text
```

But using something like that isn't working with the Yahoo one.  I think/know it's because their XML is laid out differently - they have text and quotes, whereas the Google one is just the tags with the value between ("Pennsylvania Ave SE").

How can I do the same with the Yahoo one?  (What's that type of XML called, if it has a different technical name?).

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: Note, I just tried and I **can** get the "" and "" values, since they follow my pattern I use with Google...it's the values that are inside `< ... >` that I'm unsure how to pull out.

Comment: It's all "regular" XML - those pieces of information within the opening tags are called "attributes", and you can use `getAttribute()` to access their values

Comment: Aha! That's it, thanks!!! (If you want you can put that in an Answer, and I'll mark it for ya).

Comment: There is no `<GeocodeResponse>` and no `<geometry>` in your sample XML. Are you sure that your code and your XML actually match?

Comment: @Tomalak - the `<GeocodeResponse> and <geometry>` are in [this XML](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Avenue,%20Washington%20D.C.,%20USA&sensor=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node you're trying to access is prefixed with a namespace, so you may need to define that namespace before you can access the node. Also, the `@` operator accesses an attribute within an XPath query.

The following should work to get the `temp` attribute from the `<yweather:condition>` node:

```vb
Dim doc
Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")   
doc.Async = False
doc.Load "c:\path\to\your.xml"

' Specify the namespace being used (alias = "n1")...
doc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:n1='http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'"

' Get the text of the "temp" attribute (note the "n1" namespace here)...
Debug.Print doc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/item/n1:condition/@temp").Text
```

Output:

```
84
```

If you want to get the forecast, you can use `selectNodes()` to get a nodelist and and then use `getAttribute()` to retrieve the value of a specific attribute for that particular node:

```vb
Dim n
For Each n In doc.selectNodes("/rss/channel/item/n1:forecast")
    Debug.Print n.getAttribute("day"), n.getAttribute("high")
Next
```

Output:

```
Wed           89
Thu           89
Fri           92
Sat           88
Sun           82
```

---

**Edit**, with respect to comments:

To retrieve a single value for a specific day, you can use the `[@attr=value]` syntax to find the node matching your criteria along with `/@attr` to return the attribute you're interested in. For example, here's how you can grab the high for Wednesday:

```vb
Debug.Print doc.selectSingleNode("/rss/channel/item/n1:forecast[@day='Wed']/@high").Text
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you expand on the namespace part, and using `n1` with `.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:n1='http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'"`?  That takes the place of `yweather`?

Comment: Yes. You can pick any namespace prefix you like, important is that the URI matches. The prefix is basically only there so that you don't have to write out the URI every time.

Comment: The `yweather` in `<yweather:condition>` and `<yweather:forecast>` is a namespace. If you look at your `<rss>` node, you'll see how the `yweather` namespace is declared. You need to use `setProperty` to define the namespace before you can access any nodes that use it. I'm calling it `n1`, just because it's shorter.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I follow.  Now, how would I get Wednesday's high and low from `yweather:forecast`? I tried `todayHigh = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("rss/channel").SelectSingleNode("item/n1:forecast").getAttribute("high")` but that returns `94` ...there is no "94" in that XML page...

Comment: Not sure if you reloaded the page since my edit but I included a section on how to get each day along with their highs.

Comment: How would I ask for a specific day? I.e. use `today()` to get Today's date, then how do I search for just the Wednesday "n"?  Would it have to be something like `if n.getAttribute("day") = weekday(today())`?  Of can I avoid an if statement and explicitly get today's only?

Comment: Bam! That'll do it.  I also realized that if I don't specify a day, it seems to return the first in the list.  The `94` it was returning IS in the XML, I just hadn't refreshed it in my browser to notice.  Thanks a ton @Bond!!!