# VBA Excel MSXML2.XMLHTTP getelementsbytagname() not working

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbytagname, msxml2

Here is my code

```
Sub loadrss()
    Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument, topics As Object, titleElem As Object, topic As HTMLHtmlElement, i As Integer
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "http://antt.vn/rss/trang-chu.rss", False
    http.send
    html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
    Set topics = html.getElementsByTagName("Item")
    i = 55
    For Each topic In topics
        Sheet7.Cells(i, 15).Value = topic.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).innerText
        Sheet7.Cells(i, 16).Value = topic.getElementsByTagName("link")(0).innerText
        Sheet7.Cells(i, 17).Value = topic.getElementsByTagName("pubDate")(0).innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

but it alert an error with this row

```
Sheet7.Cells(i, 15).Value = topic.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).innerText
```

I don't know how to fix it, please help!!!

Comment: Which error?  What did you learn when you Googled the error code?  What else have you tried so far to solve the issue?  *"Not Working"* is not very descriptive.

Comment: Actually I can see a couple problems already; I'll give you a hint: spelling & accuracy is important!  To help you find the problems, add this line `Option Explicit` as the first line of the module.  It's a simple but important addition to [any] module when troubleshooting, especially while learning, and it will force you to properly declare and spell names of variables, objects, properties, etc. when you try to run the code.

Comment: "Runtime error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set" I think the problem is in "http://antt.vn/rss/trang-chu.rss", my code work with another website but this, with <![CDATA[]]> is a problem? i Think!!!
I'm not a coder, not good english too, sory :D

Comment: More hints from Googling "[Runtime error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set (Click Here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx)"

Comment: Your feed is XML, not HTML.  They're not really interchangeable.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232739/get-attribute-from-xml-rss

Comment: Oh thank you @TimWilliams I see it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code. It should fetch you all the values you are after.

```
Sub XML_Parsing_ano()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmldoc As Object, post As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://antt.vn/rss/trang-chu.rss", False
        .send
        Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xmldoc.LoadXML .responseXML.XML
    End With

     For Each post In xmldoc.SelectNodes("//item")
        r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.SelectNodes(".//title")(0).Text
        Cells(r, 2) = post.SelectNodes(".//pubDate")(0).Text
        Cells(r, 3) = post.SelectNodes(".//link")(0).Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Or, If you wanna stick to `.getElementsByTagName()` then:

```
Sub XML_Parsing_ano()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmldoc As Object, post As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://antt.vn/rss/trang-chu.rss", False
        .send
        Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xmldoc.LoadXML .responseXML.XML
    End With

     For Each post In xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("item")
        r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).Text
        Cells(r, 2) = post.getElementsByTagName("pubDate")(0).Text
        Cells(r, 3) = post.getElementsByTagName("link")(0).Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr, for the plus .

Comment: Hi QHarr!! You can follow this link to see an update: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682377/select-a-single-node-xml-object-using-vba/48691608#48691608)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I shall have a gander now.

Comment: Hi @SIM, it work very well. Big thank to you. I see the difference is xmldoc.LoadXML .responseXML.XML vs html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to explore the DOM model in relation to XML. Otherwise you will end up having to try and extract information from the `OwnerDocument` along the lines of `topics(0).OwnerDocument.DocumentElement.outerText`

I am new to this so am open to feedback on this but the following is the route I would take.

There is a good example of node selection by @Vityata here: [Select a single node XML object using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682377/select-a-single-node-xml-object-using-vba)

Here is an example to get you started of extracting the pubDates.

```
Sub testing()
    
    Dim xmlhttp As XMLHTTP60

    Set xmlhttp = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60 'MSXML2.DOMDocument

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With xmlhttp
        .Open "GET", "http://antt.vn/rss/trang-chu.rss", False
        .Send
     Set objXML = .responseXML
    End With

    Dim elemList As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim elem As IXMLDOMNode
    Set elemList = objXML.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate")
   
    For Each elem In elemList
  
       Debug.Print elem.nodeTypedValue
       
    Next elem
  
End Sub
```

References (in no particular order - this is what I had a quick look at to get a handle on navigation):

1. [Combine two XMLnodelist in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364326/combine-two-xmlnodelist-in-vba)
2. [XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName Method (String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=net-7.0)
3. [VBA Web Services XML .responseXML parse](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8a6f4d15-c352-43ec-895b-527c391e7ad9/vba-web-services-xml-responsexml-parse?forum=accessdev)
4. [Node.ownerDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/ownerDocument)
5. [How to parse XML using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-using-vba)
6. [The HTML DOM Element Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)
7. [XmlHttpRequest – Http requests in Excel VBA](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)